# PHP - Post data to a database on visit of a URL?

Tags: php, url, triggers

I am fairly new at PHP.

Is it possible to post data to a database on visit of a URL?

I want the user to scan a QR code that open up a link that just echo a message. But in the back end the date and time is recorded to a database. How would I do that?

Thanks again

Comment: Write to the DB on the page load. You also could alternatively have a CRON job that scans the request log at the end of every day and populates the DB, that seems like a bit of work to go through though.

Comment: "post" data shouldn't be confused with HTTP post, and you should use a GET request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is very possible...

yourscript.php

```
<?php
$somedata=isset($_GET['somedata'])?$_GET['somedata']:null;
$conn=getYourDBConnction();
$sql='INSERT INTO yourTable(datatime,somedata) VALUES(NOW(),?);
$stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($somedata));
echo('response');
```

Comment: Thanks works fantastic. Best Regards,